# Webservice and two 'parallel' requests from client

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have such a problem. Suppose we have a client (WinForms app), which invokes some methods from webservice.
Every 5 minutes (Interval of Timer) I invoke asynchronously webmethod A. 
Suppose that time of its execution take a 1 minute.
When this operation runs, I open some Window, and invokes webmethod B synchronously...
or i try to do it. Application suspended, wait until webmethod A ends, then process webmethod B (or I have an exception - Connection was closed, or Timeout...).

Is there any possibility to run this A, B webmethods 'parallel'?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the service on a background thread using the `BackgroundWorker` component.
(Or the ThreadPool)

Depending on how you're calling the web service, you can also call the asynchronous version (Begin*XXX* and End*XXX*)

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t72866-blocking-problem-bug-with-enablesession-true-and-asynchronous-web-service-calls.html